# How do I use JQuery UI tabs with Django (or other tab-solution)?

Tags: django, jquery-ui-tabs

I would like to use the JQuery UI tabs in my Django app but how should I do that? I cannot figure it out with Django's template system.

Or, is it another smoother way to get tabs in a Django app?

Thanks
/Tobbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tobbe,

This is how I'm doing it, may not be ideal, but it works:

Create a base.html file with all the common html elements you need. Then have blocks that define different parts of the file. For instance:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>My Page</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
{% block tabs %}
Put your tab code here. The content is actually in the tab block that is why the endblock for the tabs block is after the content block.
{% block content %}Default content{% endblock content %}
{% endblock tabs %}
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does JqueryUI has to do with django templates? Those things are orthogonal - just use it the same way you would use them in html file.

Comment: Well, the example I tried to use was one html-file for all tabs in JQuery UI but for my django app I use template inheritance, having one base html and then different templates extending the base. Maybe you could provide me an example how to do it?